# How to return records with no active locations

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have two tables: table 1 lists facilities, table 2 lists facility locations (linked to facilities by facility_no field

I need to return all the active facilities **without** at least one active location. Location table has edate(end date) field which, if null, indicates the record is active. Can't refer customers to facilities with no active locations so have to find the orphaned facility records.

```
select fc.facility_no, fc.facility_fname, fc.facility_lname, fc.facility_sdate, fc.edate, loc.loctrackingno, loc.sdate, loc.edate
from facility fc
inner join Locations loc
on loc.facility_trackingNo = fc.facility_no
where isnull(count(loc.EDate)) >= 1
```

or

```
SELECT EDate, COUNT(*)
FROM locations
GROUP BY EDate
HAVING isnull(COUNT(*) > 1, "")
```

Neither of the above works

Comment: I have three dogs. One is big and dark brown, one is medium-sized and light brown and one is small and white (with some brown parts). Which one of them has fleas? 

If that wasn't clear enough - your question contains some of the information needed to answer it, but not all of it. Please check out the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Is this join expression accurate: `on loc.facility_trackingNo = fc.facility_no` does a field called `facility_trackingNo` really map to a field called `facility_no`?

Answer (score 0):

The key information from your request:

> find the orphaned facility records

This is not harder than the usual *orphan* lookups if you can identify that the criteria for "active locations" is really part of the join expression.

---

*I Removed the `loc` fields from the resultset as 'loc' does not exist for an orphan*

## NOT EXISTS

```sql
SELECT fc.facility_no, fc.facility_fname, fc.facility_lname, fc.facility_sdate, fc.edate
loc.edate
FROM facility fc
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT loc.facility_trackingNo
        FROM Locations loc
        WHERE loc.facility_trackingNo = fc.facility_no
              AND loc.edate IS NULL
    )
```

## LEFT JOIN

```sql
SELECT fc.facility_no, fc.facility_fname, fc.facility_lname, fc.facility_sdate, fc.edate
FROM facility fc
LEFT OUTER JOIN Locations loc
        ON loc.facility_trackingNo = fc.facility_no
           AND loc.edate IS NULL
WHERE loc.facility_trackingNo IS NULL
```

## NOT IN

```sql
SELECT fc.facility_no, fc.facility_fname, fc.facility_lname, fc.facility_sdate, fc.edate
loc.edate
FROM facility fc
WHERE fc.facility_no NOT IN (
        SELECT loc.facility_trackingNo
        FROM Locations loc
        WHERE loc.edate IS NULL
    )
```

---

Generally to find *orphans* you use one of these patterns:

1. Direct Query on the Orphan/child table with `NOT EXISTS` criteria for each individual row.

   ```
   SELECT <fields> 
   FROM <child table> 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS ( <expression to select the parent> )
   ```

   - This offers better performance than variations that use a sub-query to generate a count and use `WHERE <count result> = 0` because it doesn't require a seek acorss *all* matching records, meaning it should fail faster than calculating a count.
   - `NOT EXISTS` is generally easier to read as well
2. Use a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` and return only the grouped results that have a `NULL` on the parent side of the join

   ```
   SELECT <fields> 
   FROM <child table> 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN <parent table> ON <linking expression>
   WHERE <field on parent expression> IS NULL
   ```

   - There is no need to use `GROUP BY` for this technique to work, because duplications in the records only exists *if* there is a match in the join, and we have specifically excluded these rows.
3. Direct Query on the Orphan/child table with `NOT IN` criteria.

   ```
   SELECT <fields> 
   FROM <child table> 
   WHERE <linking field> NOT IN ( <linking field select query on the parent> )
   ```

   - Developers usually expect this to be more performant, but this is only true if the number of parent records is significantly lower than the number of
   - The incorrect assumption is that as we are not directly mapping rows from one result set to the other, only comparing values, that should be less work...

> **NOTE:** For more reading, and to learn about performance concerns: [T-SQL commands performance comparison – NOT IN vs SQL NOT EXISTS vs SQL LEFT JOIN vs SQL EXCEPT](https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-commands-performance-comparison-not-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-vs-except/)

*performance may not be your only reason to pick one over the other, these solutions are offered for you to compare in your own environment, sometimes one expresison is easier to read/rwrite/maintain than the others.*

---

From your attempt, `INNER JOIN` will find results where a record exists in *both* tables, so an `INNER JOIN` specifically excludes the rows you are trying to find, in-fact it specifically excludes *only* the rows that you want to find.

- You could say that an "orphaned" record is one that does not exist in the `INNER JOIN` result.

So instead we need to use an ***OUTER** JOIN* to retrieve the orphaned records as that will return rows that don't have a match on both sides of the join. Then to find the orphans.

> More information here: [Inner Join vs Outer Join](https://www.diffen.com/difference/Inner_Join_vs_Outer_Join)